# GUI Setup for Omnetpp on WSL2

Tags: installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, omnet++

I'm trying to install/setup Omnet++ on WSL2, ideally with graphics support. The [Omnet installation guide](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/InstallGuide.pdf) offers a solution through VcXserver, but according to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps), WSL2 now supports Linux GUI apps by default. Does this include the Omnetpp IDE? If so, what do I need to do to set this up (while not using VcXServer)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the Ubuntu installation guide (assuming you have installed the Ubuntu guest image in WSL2). Everything should work as expected on an up-to date WSL2 installation. You may need to set `export GDK_BACKEND=x11` as the IDE may try to use (and fail) the wayland backend.